# How can I save the same plot (shown with Plots>Export>Save) using `ggsave`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Let's say I have a `ggplot` `g`:

```
g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
g
```

[image]

Now, I want to save this plot as a `pdf` file. Before using the `ggsave` function, I explore different sizes using `Rstudio`'s Plots>Export>Save as PDF, and end up wanting the sizes shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to automate saving the plot with the same size using `ggsave`:

```
ggsave("plot.pdf", g, width = 10.26, height = 10.09)
```

However, the results are not identical. Also, the plot that was saved using `ggsave` is flipped.

How can I save the same plot (shown with Plots>Export>Save above) using `ggsave`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing your tests try to flag `portrait` instead of `landscape`.
Then in `ggsave` try adding `units = "inches"`

Comment: I want my image to be in `landscape` mode. :)

Comment: then try to invert `width` and `height` in `ggsave`